# Google Maps - How to find all Google Trekker Locations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reverse-geocoding, google-street-view

I'm currently working on a program that uses a reverse geocoder and Google's street view metadata API to generate random coordinates and locate street view locations from these coordinates.  However, I only wish to obtain road cameras, not those produced from Google Trekker.  Is there a way to find or determine all Trekker locations so I can exclude them from my dataset?

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially check if there are any other points within a small radius (3 or so metres) as trekker locations will usually have a smaller distance between each panorama than road panoramas.

Did some testing myself and found that the average for trekking panoramas is about 4 metres while for road panoramas the average is about 10 metres.

This is by no means a guaranteed solution but with tuning it could work with reasonable accuracy.